# Processing and Graphing Column in R

Tags: r, database, csv, graph, statistics

I have the following column in a CSV file called "Community Board" It has about 50 different values which are listed as 3 digit numbers. The first number applies to which borough of New York City the board is in and the second is which board it is. How can I count the frequency of each entry in my CSV file using R? For example, I want to use R to determine that 102 appears 30 times, 421 appears 56 times and so forth. Here is my pseudo code:

```
count(buildings$communityboard)
```

In other words, count the frequency of each value in the communityboard variable. Then, when it is counted, I'd like to create a graph showing the frequency of each entry.

```
  counts <- table(buildings$CommunityBoard)
  barplot(counts, main="Complaints by Community Board", 
  xlab="Community Board Number")
```

Please let me know how to proceed in doing this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at `?table`.

Comment: And do `plot(table(buildings$communityboard))` to plot it.

Comment: I got the graph to work with the code above. how can I get to count everything too?

Answer (score 0):

The code is already given by @Imo and @eipi10. I am just summarizing it here with minor updates. 
To count everything, the code is

```
table(buildings$communityboard)
```

To get the plot:

```
plot(buildings$communityboard,main="Complaints by Community Board",xlab="Community Board Number",ylab="Count")
```